# How can I optimize these MySQL requests in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this fairly complex (in terms of iterations) request on my database. The info is then used to create a chart. Here's the parts of the code and what they do.

This first query gets all the stats, does some math on the number of pulses. It chooses the four highest in the last 30 days. It then puts the results into arrays.

```
    $mostUsedStmt = $db->prepare(" 
SELECT stats_id
     , sum(pulse/interval) TotalSum 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
 GROUP 
    BY stats_id 
 ORDER  
    BY TotalSum DESC 
 LIMIT 4
");
    $mostUsedStmt->execute();
    $stats_array = Array();
    $total_array = Array();
    $name_array = Array();
    while ($row = $mostUsedStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $stats = $row['stats_id'];
        $stats_array[] = $stats;
        $total_array[] = $row['TotalSum'];

        $stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT name FROM stats WHERE id = '$stats' " );
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($namerow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $name_array[] = $namerow['name'];
        }
    }
    $number1 = $station_array[0];
    $number2 = $station_array[1];
    $number3 = $station_array[2];
    $number4 = $station_array[3];
```

I will update the above to get the `name` column in the first query, but this only loops 4x.

This next part is an array that will be the result itself, which will be json encoded and later handled by a Morris.js chart. This part of the code slows the whole script down considerably.

```
    try {
        $message = array(
            $MessageTypeId,
            array(          
                'chartData' => array(
                    'element' => 'myfirstchart',
                    'data' => array(
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-10 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 10),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 10),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 10),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 10)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-9 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 9),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 9),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 9),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 9)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-8 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 8),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 8),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 8),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 8)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-7 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 7),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 7),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 7),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 7)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-6 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 6),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 6),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 6),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 6)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-5 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 5),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 5),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 5),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 5)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-4 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 4),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 4),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 4),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 4)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-3 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 3),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 3),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 3),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 3)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-2 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 2),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 2),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 2),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 2)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-1 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 1),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 1),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 1),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 1)
                        ),
                        array(
                            'period' => date('d.m.', strtotime('-0 days')),
                            $number1 => getvalue($number1, 0),
                            $number2 => getvalue($number2, 0),
                            $number3 => getvalue($number3, 0),
                            $number4 => getvalue($number4, 0)
                        )
                    ),
                    'ykeys' => array($number1, $number2, $number3, $number4),
                    'labels' => array($number1name, $number2name, $number3name, $number4name),
                    'pointSize' => 3,
                    'hideHover' => 'auto',
                    'smooth' => true,
                    'pointSize' => 6,
                    'postUnits' => ' pt',
                    'xLabels' => "day",
                    'parseTime' => false,
                    'lineColors' => array('#94c11f','#5bc0de','#ec971f', '#999')
                )
            )
        );
```

The `getValue()` function below gets the daily numbers for the four best datapoint, resulting from the first query of the code (above). As you can see, this requires over 40 requests to be made, just to get the data for four datapoints over a period of ten days. It is obvious to me that I could iterate the ten days with a `for` statement, instead of writing out each day by hand, but this would not solve the number of queries.

```
function getvalue($statsid, $days) {    
    $db = ConnectDB::getConnection();

    $datetodayStmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT sum(pulse/interval) TotalSum FROM mutable WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_to)) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL $days DAY) AND stats = '$statsid' GROUP BY stats ORDER BY TotalSum DESC LIMIT 1 ");
    $datetodayStmt->execute();
    $datetoday = $datetodayStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $date0 = round($datetoday['TotalSum'],2);

    ConnectDB::closeConnection($db);

    return $date0;
}
```

The reason each query is sent individually is because there is a "large" number of datapoints and days, many combinations. Is there a better way to query the database to cut down the number of queries, but still get all the datapoints?

Comment: Maybe get rid of the second query and do a `join`. Also you're misusing prepared statements. Correct usage is `$stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT name FROM stats WHERE id = ?" ); then you'd bind the `id`.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see execution plan.  For the first query, we expect MySQL to make effective use of index `... ON mytable (stats_id, time_to, ... )`   (with those two columns as the leading columns, in that order.  If the index also includes `pulse` and `interval`, then it would be a covering index for the query.

Comment: Why does the query in `getvalue` use `GROUP BY stats` when it's selecting a specific `stats = $statsid`? It can only return a single row, so there's no need for `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

Comment: Echoing @Barmar: the `GROUP BY` on an expression , with equality predicate on the same expression, along with the `ORDER BY DESC` and `LIMIT 1` is headscratchingly obfuscated. Looks like the query is going to return a single row; are we actually expecting more than one row? We owe it to the future reader to explain the corner case (a demonstration test case?) where we would need the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXPLAIN` to see execution plan.  For the first query, we expect MySQL to make effective use of index

```
... ON mytable (stats_id, time_to, ... )
```

with those two columns as the leading columns, in that order. MySQL will be able to use the index to satisfy the GROUP BY, avoiding a potentially expensive "Using filesort" operation.  We'd also expect MySQL can satisfy the condition on time_to from the index.         If the index also includes `pulse` and `interval`, then it would be a covering index for the query.

We could also combine the first and second queries. That second query is only four extra queries, but we could avoid those extra round trips.

```
SELECT r.stats_id
     , r.totalsum
     , s.name
  FROM ( SELECT t.stats_id
              , SUM(t.pulse/t.interval) AS totalsum
           FROM mytable t
          WHERE t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
          GROUP
             BY t.stats_id
          ORDER
             BY totalsum DESC
          LIMIT 4
       ) r
  LEFT
  JOIN stats s
    ON s.id = r.stats_id
 ORDER
    BY r.totalsum DESC
```

---

It looks like the big rock performance problem is the third query, and the functions wrapped around the `time_to` column, which prevent MySQL from using a range scan operation on a suitable index.

That's bad enough, but putting that in a tight loop to revisit the same rows over and over, to get another stat, that's going to be painful.

First, get rid of the functions around `time_to`, and do it like we did in the first query, condition on the bare column. With those functions wrapped around `time_to`, those have to be evaluated for *every* flipping row in the table (or at least every row that isn't filtered out by some other criteria.  Do all of the futzing with date math over on the right side of the comparison, on a constant, only gets done once (when the query is executed), not for every row.

And use conditional aggregation to get multiple stats.

For the sake database performance, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -10 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -9 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_10day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -9 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -8 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_09day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -8 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -7 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_08day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -7 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -6 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_07day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -6 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -5 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_06day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -5 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -4 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_05day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -4 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -3 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_04day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -3 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -2 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_03day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -2 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -1 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_02day
     , SUM( IF(t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  -1 DAY) AND t.time_to < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL   0 DAY) , t.pulse/t.interval , NULL ) AS totalsum_01day

  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.stats = 'someval'
   AND t.time_to >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -10 DAY )
```

Since we are getting `stats = 'someval'` we shouldn't need a `GROUP BY stats`. The `GROUP BY` clause on the `stats` column, along with the `ORDER BY DESC` and `LIMIT 1` in the original query are a bit puzzling... are we expecting more than one row?

The condition in the WHERE clause gets us all the rows we're interested in. From a cursory look at the spec, looks like we want the past 10 days.

The expressions in the SELECT list look complicated, but if we squint real hard, the form we see is

```
  SUM( IF( somecondition ,  t.pulse/t.interval , NULL )
```

The expression `somecondition` gets evaluated in a boolean context, for each row. If it evaluates to TRUE, we return values from the row, else, we return NULL.

What's complicated, partially because `time_to` is stored as unix-style integer number of seconds, is testing whether `time_to` falls in a particular day

```
  IF( t.time_to >=  beginning_of_day AND t.time_to < beginning_of_next_day
```

Just like the first query, this calls out for an index

```
 ... ON mytable (stats, time_to, ...)
```

That's because the query has an equality predicate on the leading column (`stats`), and then a range check on the next column (`time_to`).  Including `pulse` and `interval` columns in the index would make it a covering index, so the query could be satisfied entirely from the index, without any lookups to pages in the underlying table.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. There is one typo in the 10 day query, `) AS totalsum_10day` should be  `) ) AS totalsum_10day` (missing bracket on each day's line), but otherwise it works very well. The only thing that I will need to research is getting result by date, not by the last 24 hours, 48 hours, etc., as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single query to get all the results for the top 4 IDs that you got from the first query, and save it in a static variable.

```
<?php     
function getvalue($statsid, $days, $all_statsids) {
    static $results = [];
    if (empty($results)) {
        $db = ConnectDB::getConnection();

        $datetodayStmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT stats, days, ROUND(sum(pulse/interval), 2) TotalSum
FROM mutable 
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS days UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10) AS d
ON DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_to)) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL days DAY)
WHERE stats IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
GROUP BY stats, days");
        $datetodayStmt->execute($all_statsids);
        while ($row = $datetodayStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $results[$row['stats']][$row['days']] = $row['TotalSum'];
        }
        ConnectDB::closeConnection($db);
    }
    return $results[$statsid][$days];
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
$number1 = getvalue($number[0], 1, $station_array);
```